# How to remove first string and comma from a text file

Tags: java, file

!
[image: I have a text, the content looks like [1,'I am java, and I am happy,......'], I want to remove the first integer and the comma. When I was run the code above, the result start with last comma]

I have a text, the content looks like [1,'I am java, and I am happy, I am.....'], I want to remove the first integer and the comma. When I was run the code above, but the result start with last comma: I am......

Comment: Okay. This question makes no sense. Can you post your code and/or complete the question?

Comment: There's two commas in your text...

Comment: You want to remove it from file or it is a simple text ?

Comment: yes, there are couple of commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this following code as:

```
System.out.println(line.substring(2));
```

sub string takes the beginning index as a parameter and splits the string from that index to till the end.

Comment: make this answer as correct so others wont answer further.

Comment: I made it. Thank you.

Comment: Nit pick, but this would be removing everything before the first comma, what about the leading `[`? That would end up looking like `'I am java, and I am happy, I am.....']`? Happy to be wrong on that point as there is a significant lack of context to the question...

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to remove commas from a String, you can use `String.replaceAll(",","");` If you want to replace them by spaces, use `String.replaceAll(","," "):`

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    contents.append(line.replaceAll(","," ");
}
```

Also in your code you seem to split the input, but don't use the result of this operation.

Comment: *"I want to remove the first integer and the comma"*

Comment: how can I remove the " ' "? I tried your method, but the " ' " still be there.

Comment: @Mad you should use the `int x = Integer.parseInt(value);Matcher m = p.matcher(x); x = m.replaceAll(""); Syso(x);`

Comment: But your solution is removing ALL the commas, the question clearly states the first number and comma - just saying...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [**`indexOf`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character, starting the search at the specified index..

[**`lastIndexOf`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified substring, searching backward starting at the specified index.

```
System.out.print(s.substring(s.indexOf(",")+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are using `lastIndexOf()`. Use `indexOf()` to get the first index as shown below.

`System.out.println(test.substring(line.indexOf(',')+1));`

Comment: Thank you, anirudh, I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking your `String` literially, but you could use `String#replaceFirst`, for example...

```
String text = "[1,'I am java, and I am happy, I am.....']";
text = text.replaceFirst("\\[\\d,", "[");
System.out.println(text);
```

Which outputs...

```
['I am java, and I am happy, I am.....']
```

If you want to update the file, you are either going to have to read all the lines into some kind of `List` (modifying them as you please) and once finished, write the `List` back to the file (after you've closed it after reading it).

Alternatively, you could write each updated line to a second file, once you're finished, close both files, delete the first and rename the second back in it's place...

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
      String[] s=line.splite(",");
      String m="";
      for(int i=1;i<s.length;i++)
      {
      String m=m+s[i];
      }
      br.append(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

> String input = "[1,'I am java, and I am happy, I am.....']";
>
> //Getting String after first comma
>
> String output = StringUtils.substringAfter(input, ",");
>   System.out.println("Output:"+output);
>
> //replacing commas;
>
> System.out.println("Final o/p:"+StringUtils.replace(output, ",",""));

You can use methods in StringUtils Class for string manipulations. For using StringUtils methods, you need to import apache-commons-lang.jar file. Using this API you can manipulate many String related methods. For more details, you can see the link

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: This solution is awesome, give me a lot of information, thank you very much